# Working with Espresso.registerIdlingResources()

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I need to write test using Espresso. This test must click the button, waiting 3 seconds (application will loading text in TextView in this time) and then check, is the TextView contains text. I am using next code for it:

```
onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click());

IdlingResource idlingResource = new ElapsedTimeIdlingResource(3000);
Espresso.registerIdlingResources(idlingResource);

onView(withId(R.id.label)).check(matches(withText("Some text")));

Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(idlingResource);
```

ElapsedTimeIdlingResource class available on [GitHub](https://github.com/chiuki/espresso-samples/blob/master/idling-resource-elapsed-time/app/src/androidTest/java/com/sqisland/espresso/idling_resource/elapsed_time/ElapsedTimeIdlingResource.java).

It looks like waiting algorithm doesn't work and checking launching immediately after click. Is the registerIdlingResources() must freeze thread on 3 seconds? Or here is some callback needed?

P.S. Also here is a plroblem with logging. `Log.d()` and `System.out.println()` doesn't printing. Is there some way to log?

Comment: Just tried similar code and it works. No need for any thread sleep. Problem should be somewhere else (not in the code you provided). Make sure your `registerIdlingResources`, `check`,  `unregisterIdlingResources` code is placed in one test.

Comment: @MyDogTom, ok, thanks. But how it's works? Just for understanding.

Comment: Espresso will wait until all registered `idlingResource`'s become idle (`isIdleNow()` returns `true`) before executing view operations. See [IdlingResource class overview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/IdlingResource.html)

Comment: I experienced a similar issue in where I was not able to step forward to second call of onView(...) method. It was freezing in the first call of onView(...). In my case I was registering my XIdlingResource before any test have been executed and unregistering it after all the tests have been executed. When I removed registering, everything started to work as expected. Still seems interesting though.